# change local group from scv

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

maby some can help.
I'm trying to build script that change local group (from scv file of computers) and put in the group user "samaccountname"(from scv file).

```
function Add-LocalUser{
     Param(
        $computer=$env:testw10,
        $group='Remote Desktop Users',
        $userdomain=$env:userdomain,
        $username=$env:user01
    )
        ([ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$Group,group").psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://$domain/$user").path)
}
```

[image: example scv]

Comment: How are you running this? Do you get any errors and if so, what is the exact error message? I'm not sure what's up with `$env:testw10` and `$env:user01` but that might not matter at this point.

Comment: You have not defined the values for variables `$domain` and `$user`, so you are using $null values there. As aside, why the strange extension `scv` where it is called `Comma Separated Values`, so `csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you are using undefined variables in your code.

Try this:

```
function Add-LocalUser {
     Param(
        [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,       # default: YOUR COMPUTER
        [string]$UserName     = $env:USERNAME,           # default: YOU
        [string]$Group        = 'Remote Desktop Users',
        [string]$Domain       = $env:USERDOMAIN          # default: YOUR DOMAIN

    )
    ([ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/$Group,group").psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://$Domain/$UserName").path)
}

# next read the csv file and add the user(s) using your function
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\renatb\Desktop\Scripts\test7n.scv' | ForEach-Object {
    Add-LocalUser -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -UserName $_.SamAccountName
}
```